# solution verification: find characteristic of integral domain under given conditions

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification

Okay, so this seems an easy problem, but I was having doubts if my solution was correct or not. I would really appreciate if somebody could verify it for me.
Suppose $R$ is an integral domain  such that $20 .1 =0$ and $12 . 1 =0$ then what is the characteristic of $R$?
Here, $n.1=0$ means $1$ added $n$ times equals $0$.
**My solution**:  I'm going to use the result that if $R$ is an integral domain then characteristic of $R$= $0$ or a prime, $p$.
clearly, here char$R \neq 0$, so it must be a prime, say $p$. Since$20 .1 =0$and $p$ is the smaalest positive integer such that $p.1=0$, so $p$ divides $20$, similarly, $p$ also divides $12$ and as $2$ is the only prime to do so, we can conclude that char$R=2$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that reasoning is correct.