# Finding characteristic of an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Question:Suppose that R is an integral domain in which $20 \cdot 1=0$ and $12\cdot 1=0$.
>   What is Characteristic of R.

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this question.
An integral domain contains no zero-divisors. This is equivalent to the statement that for any two elements $a,b \in R$: $a \cdot b=0$ implies that either a or b is zero.

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you come across the integral domain $Z_3=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$? This is the ring of integers modulo $3$. In this domain $12\cdot1=0$ (but $20\cdot1\ne0$ so this isn't a possible example for $R$).

Comment: Yes, I have come across the ring you mentioned. But in this Integral domain, the element 12 certainly isn't in $Z_{3}$ and neither is the element 20. I'm having a bit of problem understanding what the author wants here.@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: There is a thing you should know: the characteristic of any integral domain is a prime number, or $0$. Now, if $p$ is the characteristic of $R$, you know that $20$ and $12$ are multiples of $p$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Well, Suppose the characteristic of R is a prime p. 
Then, for any element x,y in R: px=0 and py=0
Any multiples of p is an integer, say $\alpha$: $\alpha x=0$ and $\alpha y=0$@Crostul

Comment: In a general (unital) ring $R$, often sometimes uses an integer $n$ to denote the element $\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_n$, and sometimes (including when $n$ is the characteristic of $R$) this is the zero element $0_R$ of $R$.

Comment: @Crostul I'll add that p is a common divisor of 20 and 12.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373798/solution-verification-find-characteristic-of-integral-domain-under-given-condit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic of a domain is a prime number $p$ or $0$.

To clarify things, the notation $12\cdot1$ means $\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{\text{$12$ summands}}$, where $1$ denotes the ring's identity element.

Note that the characteristic is the additive order of the identity element, unless the identity has infinite order (when the characteristic is $0$). Why must it be prime for a domain, if nonzero?

Hint: suppose the characteristic is a composite number $mn$; can you find a zero divisor?

From the assumptions the characteristic is nonzero and you have that $p\mid 20$ and $p\mid 12$.

> Then $p\mid\gcd(20,12)$.

Comment: I've solved for p=1 which I believe it should be correct.

Comment: @Mathematicing huh? you need to find a prime number $p$ such that $p\mid \gcd(20,12)$.

Comment: @Mathematicing No, $1$ is not a prime number. The only ring with characteristic $1$ is the trivial ring $\{0\}$ and in a domain $1\ne0$ by definition.